# Grep ignoring/not catching first line of file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I am trying to do a script that read all lines of a file and grep a line if contains the expecify word in the grep (in this case the word is apple), but I am having a issue that the grep is ignoring/not catching the first line of the file.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line;
do
    grep 'apple' > fruits2.txt
    
done < fruits.txt
```

The input file  "fruits.txt"

```
apple 1
banana
apple 2
grape
orange
apple 3
blueberry
apple 4
```

The output file "fruits2.txt"

```
apple 2
apple 3
apple 4
```

Comment: `read line` reads the first line, grep doesn't even see it.

Comment: Just use `grep 'apple' fruits.txt > fruits2.txt`, no need for the loop.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are creating a loop, in order to read an entire file line by line, and let `grep` verify if there is something inside that line.

You are correct that `grep` can read just a single line.

But: `grep` **can read an entire file**, that's what is has been created for.

So, you don't need to create your own loop, you can just do:

```
grep "apple" fruits.txt
```

The result will be:

```
apple 1
apple 2
apple 3
apple 4
```

As an extra: imagine that you add "pineapple 666" to your "fruits.txt" file, then you will see this one too in your output. In case you don't want that:

```
grep -w "apple" fruits.txt
```

(the `-w` says that only entire words may be shown.)